# What happens when my domain provider cancels order after domain transfer?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

A year has gone missing from my domains. What can I do to get it back?

Here is the complete history (I have assumed abc.com and xyz.in as the domain names as I do not want to disclose my own domain names)

abc.com and xyz.in were registered on November 2012 via a reseller of Webiq

On November 2013, I was notified about the expiration of these two domains. When I contacted my reseller explaining that I would like to transfer the domains to GoDaddy he told that I was to renew them in order to transfer. So

abc.com and xyz.in were renewed on November 2013 via the same reseller of Webiq

I had started the transfers via GoDaddy to whom I paid a minimal fee (and they even offered 1 addition year for each domain on the renewal)

On 17th November 2013
abc.com got transferred from Webiq to Godaddy. The records showed it's valid till 11/05/2015

on 18th January 2014
xyz.in got transferred from Webiq to GoDaddy. The records showed it's valid till 11/3/2016

Two weeks ago from today when I logged into my cpanel it notified that my domain was getting expired soon and that I renew it. This was surprising because it's supposed to be valid till 11/05/2015 but both my domains seemed to show one year lesser now! On contacting GoDaddy they requested that I contact my old registrar as the one missing one year must've been because of them

When I tried submitting a support request to Webiq whether they cancelled it, they replied:

> Your domain "abc.com" has been transferred away from us on 17-11-2013 and the domain "xyz.in" was transferred away from us on 18-01-2014. There are no order cancellation actions placed. If you have any billing related issues kindly contact your parent reseller.

GoDaddy has now made me aware of something called the 45-day rule which clearly states that I am to get a refund for the renewal as the old registrar (webiq) would have gained this refund regardless of whether they made a refund or not!

I found the details of this in this link >> [Transfer of Recently Renewed Domains](https://www.namesilo.com/Support/Transfer-of-Recently-Renewed-Domains)

Comment: For the missing year, contact the provider (webiq)...

Comment: 2013 + 1 year + 1 year = 2015 (admittedly this is still _next_ year), but where do you get 2016 from? After the domains were renewed what did the Whois records report?

Comment: GoDaddy provided 1 year extra on each domain on transfer. I've added that into account. Sorry I forgot to mention that. let me add that too..

Comment: Hang on... abc.com is gone I assume since it's 9 months past? Nothing you can do, other than buy it back? What does GoDaddy have to do with this if Webiq are the current host?

Comment: @Dave It would seem that GoDaddy are the current registrar... the domain was transferred to them (from Webiq) at the end of 2013. I think the question should be... "What does Webiq have to do with this if GoDaddy are the current host?"

Comment: Still a minor query... you say the domains are "getting expired this year", but the "whois also shows 2015" - that's _next_ year, yes?

Comment: @w3d right. Thanks for this (taking the time etc), I had totally missed the question!

Comment: Apparently there is something called a 45-day rule due to which my renewal amount was refunded back to the old registrar (Webiq) but they notified my reseller about this refund. I am trying to get a refund now.

Answer (score 1):

Since your domain were expiring in 2013, you could have acquired them directly from GoDaddy rather than paying something to your old provider. Godaddy would have been able to pick your domains, even if they were previously owned by Webiq.

Since you have now transferred your domains, the information provided by GoDaddy about expiration is relevant, not that of your old provider.

```
This is confusing as I have no idea who to blame for the missing one year.
```

Your old domain provider is not responsible in this case. You should address this issue with GoDaddy.

Comment: Expired Oct 2013 - so not expired yet?

Comment: Are we in 2013? I am not talking about what SHOULD be done, but COULD have been be done differently.

Comment: They were "notified" that the domains would expire in Oct 2013 (they didn't didn't actually expire), at which point they renewed it, transferred it and added some more years to the registration at the new registrar (a total of 3 years by the sounds of it), but it seems that 1 of these years has since "disappeared"?!

Comment: Yes one of the years expired!

Comment: @Saifur I have updated my answer. IMHO, you should raise this issue with GoDaddy only.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll ask them and get back with their reply. Thanks a lot to everyone!!